# Htacces redirecting on url with parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect via htacces on url with parameter ofr example:

domain1.com/asd -> domain2.com/sdew;as
domain1.com/ase -> domain2.com/sdew;aw

I use in htacces conditions as bellow:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^aa/bb-l(/.*)?$ http://www.domain2.com/ssd/sdew;as [R=301,L,NC]
```

This rule redirect from domain1.com/asd to http://www.domain2.com/ssd/sdew%3bas

not to http://www.domain2.com/ssd/sdew;as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change flags [R=301,L,NC] to **[R=301,L,NC,NE]**

> **NE**|noescape
>
> By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be
>   converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents
>   that from happening.
>
> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Solution above is good but does not work with letters specific for polish language. For example if I want to redirect from domain1.com-**ł**aa/bb-to domain2.com/ssd/sdew;as this htacces dont work. My htacces bellow  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^aaa/łaaa-l(/.*)?$ http://www.domain2.com/sdf/ase;as [R=301,L,NC,NE]